# Angular making pseudo-synchronous HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to construct a mechanism that would access a database via POST requests. So far, I do received the desired data, but am have issues with the **timing**. Here are three pieces of code that I'm using (simplified to keep the focus of the question).

First, a factory handling the HTTP request vis-à-vis a servlet:

```
var My_Web = angular.module('My_Web'); 

My_Web.factory('DB_Services', function($http , $q) {
    var l_Result ;
    var DB_Services = function(p_Query) {
                            var deferred = $q.defer();
                            var url     = "http://localhost:8080/demo/servlets/servlet/Test_ui?";
                            var params  = "data=" + p_Query ;
                            var Sending = url + params ;

                            $http.post(Sending).
                                        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                             deferred.resolve(data);
                                        }).
                                        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                             deferred.reject(status);
                                        });
                                         return deferred.promise;
        
                        }
                      
    return DB_Services;
    });
```

Second, a general purpose function handling the `promise` (or so I meant) exposed to all the controllers that would need to extract data from the remote DB:

```
$rootScope.Get_Data_from_DB = function(p_Query) {
    DB_Services(p_Query).then(function(d) {
        console.log("In Get_Data_from_DB; Received data is: " + JSON.stringify(d));
        $scope.data = d;
    });
};
```

Third, one example within one of the controllers:

```
$scope.Search_Lookups = function () {
    
    console.log ("search for lookup data...") ;
    
    var l_Lookup_Type = document.getElementById("THISONE").value ;

    var l_Send_Request_Data = '{"Requestor_ID":"4321" , "Request_Details" : { "Data_type" : "' + l_Lookup_Type + '" } }' ;
    
    console.log("Sending Request: " + l_Send_Request_Data) ;
    
    l_Data = $rootScope.Get_Data_from_DB(p_Query) ;
    
    console.log ("Received response: " + l_Data) ;

    Deploy_data(l_Data) ;
    
}
```

The function `Deploy_data(l_Data)` is responsible of dismembering the received data and put the relevant pieces on screen.

What happens is that I get on the console the string `Received response: undefined` and immediately after the result of the retrieval as `In Get_Data_from_DB; Received data is: (here I get the data)`.

The `Received response: undefined` is printed from the invoking function (third piece of code), whereas the output with the actual data is received and printed from within the second piece of code above. This means that the invocation to `Deploy_data` would not receive the extracted data.

Once again, the same mechanism (i.e. the factory `$rootScope.Get_Data_from_DB`) would be vastly used by many controllers.

I thought of using `$scope.$watch` but I'm not sure because the same user might be triggering several queries at the same time (e.g. request a report that might take few seconds to arrive and, in the meantime, ask for something else).

Comment: so you need to cascade the calls? does the calls depend on each other?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your question. The call sequence is: (from within a controller) Search_Lookups -> $rootScope.Get_Data_from_DB -> DB_Services . Is this what you were asking?

Comment: Forgot you include your name @Radu. Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand your question. The call sequence is: (from within a controller) Search_Lookups -> $rootScope.Get_Data_from_DB -> DB_Services . Is this what you were asking?

Comment: yes that is was i was asking if you want them async or not. By default angular does the calls async. To solved this issue  i remember i've somehow cascaded the calls so I've called the second one on the success response from the first one. Please let me know if you understand

Comment: I think I got it, but it would look as a not-so-good approach. Imagine that the `$scope.Get_Data_from_DB` has tens of possible **clients**. It would make a mess and very difficult to maintain. Best would be to actually "WAIT" for the response to arrive (in which case a timeout should be charged to prevent deadlocks).

Comment: you can't set a timeout because you don't know the exact time of the request sometime  can go like 1 sec sometime like 5 sec so you can't set a timeout. Maybe the best is to set a variable and get a watch on that variable and when it changed you just need to do the next call. I'm just thinking maybe is not the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution (at least it appears to be ok for the time being). The global function `Get_Data_from_DB` accepts a second parameter which is a callback of the invoking controller.

The invoking controller creates a private instance of the `Get_Data_from_DB` function and triggers a request providing the callback function.

I'll need to test this with parallel queries, but that is still a long way to go...